# how to monitor sip packets on android phone/

Tags: android, sip

I am new to android. I would like to monitor the sip packets that my application sends and receive. How to do that? I need some help.

My android phone is a Samsung.
Appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following packet sniffers for android: (Note, you might need to root your phone for this to work)

1. **Packet Sniffer**: https://sites.google.com/site/androidarts/packet-sniffer
2. **Andro shark**: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/capture-network-traffic-with-andro-shark/

Andro shark in particular can store the captures in a format that can be opened by [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the desktop.

Comment: how can i become root on my phone?

Comment: What is the exact phone model that you own?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how to sniff all traffic from any mobile phone, which has WiFi. It does not require root access or anything else, all you need is USB WiFi adapter (5$ for "made in Chine" adapter).

1. Setup WiFi access point using PC and USB WiFi adapter.
2. Connect Android phone to newly created WiFi AP
3. Use wireshark on your PC in order to sniff all traffic, that goes through WiFi adapter.

Hope it helps.